# WPF RadioButton/ToggleButton styling

Tags: wpf, styles, radio-button, togglebutton

I would like to mimic a style for a group of ToggleButtons as in the below image. Only one of the buttons can be "Checked" at any time.

[image]

My question is related to styling:

- I'd like to have rounded corners on the leftmost button and the rightmost button as in the image but if there is a button between (like in the image), that should not have rounded corners. Sometimes there might only be two buttons to toggle.
- I need style for different states: "Normal/Unchecked", "Mouseover", "Pressed" and "Checked" at the minimum.

The current control I am using for this is done like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="All" Padding="12,8,12,8" GroupName="View"  />
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="Geolocated" Padding="12,8,12,8" GroupName="View" />
    <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="Non Geolocated" Padding="12,8,12,8" GroupName="View" />
</StackPanel>
```

In the StackPanel Resources I am trying to set Style for ToggleButton but I'm pretty lost how to achieve the result as in the image above.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This may not be the easiest/best approach, but I took a stab at knocking up some `ControlTemplates` using Kaxaml, to produce something that looks like this:

[image: Button Preview]

You could store these templates in a `ResourceDictionary` and apply them when required, or use them if you were building your button list on the fly.

I actually created three slightly different styles, one for the left and right buttons, and one for the middle (you may be able to simplify this with extending/inheriting styles). Some repeated code omitted.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!-- Brushes for colours/backgrounds -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FontBrush" Color="#DDDDDD"/>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BgBrush1" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#888888"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#222222"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush1" Color="#333333"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#555555"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#111111"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <!-- Left Button Template -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonLeft" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Border
                Name="Border"
                Background="{StaticResource BgBrush1}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush1}"
                BorderThickness="1"
                CornerRadius="5,0,0,5">
                <ContentPresenter
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold"
                    TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource FontBrush}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#808080"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CheckedBrush}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!-- Middle Button(s) Template -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonMid" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Border
                Name="Border"
                Background="{StaticResource BgBrush1}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush1}"
                BorderThickness="0,1,0,1"
                CornerRadius="0" />
        <!-- Other code identical to Left Button Template -->       
        </ControlTemplate>

        <!-- Right Button Template -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonRight" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Border
                Name="Border"
                Background="{StaticResource BgBrush1}"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush1}"
                BorderThickness="1"
                CornerRadius="0, 5, 5, 0" />
        <!-- Other code identical to Left Button Template -->  
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <!-- Example Usage -->
    <Grid Background="#555555">
        <StackPanel Height="25" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5">
            <RadioButton Content="All" GroupName="View" Padding="2" Template="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonLeft}"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Geolocated" GroupName="View" Padding="2" Template="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonMid}"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Non Geolocated" GroupName="View" Padding="2" Template="{DynamicResource ToggleButtonRight}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

You would have to add additional `Triggers` etc. for the `IsPressed` state, and any others required (e.g `IsEnabled`).

Comment: This sample code was very beautiful and useful, thank you

Comment: Glad it was still useful after all this time!